# I'm not getting all results. Web scraping with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new working in web scraping with python and selenium. I have one problem with my script, and it's that I don't get all url from the page. It should be 80 urls, but I only get 20. Also, I would like to know who get in the url and extract the data from it. I have one solution for that, but I would like to know who do it the same thing with selenium.

Imports

```py
import requests
import lxml.html as html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, wait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Code

```py
def car_url():
    ser = Service("D:/Usuario/Desktop/chrome_driver/chromedriver.exe")
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.contactcars.com/en/cars/new/summary?page=1")

    links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                 '//a[@class="car-card__engines__body__list__item__link"]')

    for link in links:
        response = requests.get(link.get_attribute('href'))
        if response.status_code == 200:
            try:
                home = response.content.decode('utf-8')
                parsed = html.fromstring(home)
                name = parsed.xpath('//div[@class="d-inline-block"]/text()')
                model = parsed.xpath(
                    '//div[@class="d-inline-block margin-start--sm"]/text()')
                engine = parsed.xpath(
                    '//div[contains(@class,"engine-title")]/text()')
                print(
                    f"Car name = {str(name)} Model = {str(model)} Engine = {str(engine)}")
            except IndexError as e:
                print(e)

    driver.close()
```

I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: it looks like the page has pagination & lazy loading in it, you might have to make it scroll till the bottom & then run the selenium code

Comment: Have you printed `links` to see what you're actually getting back?

Comment: You can check your xpath in developer's tool first, if it's giving correct number of links.

Comment: Might want to check the api.

Answer (score 0):

The web page you want to view dynamically updates elements as you scroll down.

So you have to scroll all the way down to scrap all the objects from that webpage.

The code below is a modified version of your code.
(It takes 2m 45.5s in my machine)

Imports

```
import time
import requests
import lxml.html as html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, wait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

New function for scroll down

```
def scroll_down_all(driver, pause_sec=1):

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Pause
    time.sleep(pause_sec)

    # After scroll down, get current height.
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    
    last_height = new_height
```

Modified your code function

```
def car_url():
    
    ser = Service("D:/Usuario/Desktop/chrome_driver/chromedriver.exe")
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.contactcars.com/en/cars/new/summary?page=1")

    scroll_down_all(driver, pause_sec=1) # New function for scroll down
    
    links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                 '//a[@class="car-card__engines__body__list__item__link"]')

    print(len(links))
    for link in links:
        response = requests.get(link.get_attribute('href'))
        if response.status_code == 200:
            try:
                home = response.content.decode('utf-8')
                parsed = html.fromstring(home)
                name = parsed.xpath('//div[@class="d-inline-block"]/text()')
                model = parsed.xpath(
                    '//div[@class="d-inline-block margin-start--sm"]/text()')
                engine = parsed.xpath(
                    '//div[contains(@class,"engine-title")]/text()')
                print(
                    f"Car name = {str(name)} Model = {str(model)} Engine = {str(engine)}")
            except IndexError as e:
                print(e)

    driver.close()
```

Results of this code

```
Car name = ['Alfa Romeo Giulia '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T Base ']
Car name = ['Alfa Romeo Giulia '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T Super ']
Car name = ['Alfa Romeo Giulia '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T Veloce ']
Car name = ['Alfa Romeo Giulietta '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['1.4 A/T premium ']
Car name = ['Alfa Romeo Giulietta veloce '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['1.8 A/T F/O ']
Car name = ['Alfa Romeo Stelvio '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T Turbo Super ']
Car name = ['Alfa Romeo Stelvio '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T Turbo Super plus ']
Car name = ['Aston Martin Vantage '] Model = ['2020'] Engine = ['4.0 A/T F/O Coupe ']
Car name = ['Audi A3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.4 A/T Advanced ']
Car name = ['Audi A3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.4 A/T S-Line ']
Car name = ['Audi A4 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T S-Line ']
Car name = ['Audi A4 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T S-Line plus ']
Car name = ['Audi A5 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T S-Line ']
Car name = ['Audi A6 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T S-Line ']
Car name = ['Audi Q2 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.4 A/T Advanced ']
Car name = ['Audi Q2 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.4 A/T S line ']
Car name = ['Audi Q3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.4 A/T Advanced ']
Car name = ['Audi Q3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.4 A/T S-Line New Rim ']
Car name = ['Audi Q3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.4 A/T Sport back with New Rim ']
Car name = ['Audi Q3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T Sport back ']
Car name = ['Audi Q7 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T TFSI Premium ']
Car name = ['Audi Q8 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['3.0 A/T S-Line ']
Car name = ['Audi Q8 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['3.0 A/T S-Line Plus ']
Car name = ['Audi RS Q8 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['4.0 A/T TFSI Quattro ']
Car name = ['BAIC X3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Comfort ']
Car name = ['BAIC X3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Comfort Plus ']
Car name = ['BAIC X3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Luxury ']
Car name = ['BAIC X3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Luxury Plus ']
Car name = ['BAIC X5 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo ']
Car name = ['BAIC X7 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo Elite ']
Car name = ['BAIC X7 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo Premium ']
Car name = ['BMW 118i '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Sport line ']
Car name = ['BMW 218 '] Model = ['2020'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T F/O Exclusive 7 Seats ']
Car name = ['BMW 218i '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Gran Coupe ']
Car name = ['BMW 320i '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T Exclusive ']
Car name = ['BMW 520i '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['1.6 A/T Luxury ']
Car name = ['BMW 730Li '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T F/O ']
Car name = ['BMW 740Li '] Model = ['2020'] Engine = ['3.0 A/T Pure Excellence ']
Car name = ['BMW 750i '] Model = ['2020'] Engine = ['4.4 F/O A/T ']
Car name = ['BMW M850i '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['4.4 F/O A/T Gran Coupe ']
Car name = ['BMW X1 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T X-Line ']
Car name = ['BMW X1 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Sport ']
Car name = ['BMW X2 '] Model = ['2020'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Exclusive ']
Car name = ['BMW X2 '] Model = ['2020'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T M-Sport ']
Car name = ['BMW X3 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T 30i New Shape ']
Car name = ['BMW X3 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['3.0 A/T M40i New Shape ']
Car name = ['BMW X4 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T 30i M ']
Car name = ['BMW X5 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['3.0 A/T 40i ']
Car name = ['BMW X5 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['4.4 F/O A/T M50i ']
Car name = ['BMW X6 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['4.4 F/O A/T M50i-Sport ']
Car name = ['BMW X7 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['4.4 A/T M50i ']
Car name = ['BMW Z4 '] Model = ['2020'] Engine = ['2.0 A/T M-Sport Roadster ']
Car name = ['BMW i8 '] Model = ['2020'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Coupe LCI ']
Car name = ['BMW i8 '] Model = ['2020'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Roadster ']
Car name = ['BYD F3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 M/T ']
Car name = ['BYD F3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T ']
Car name = ['BYD L3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T GLX ']
Car name = ['BYD L3 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T GS ']
Car name = ['Bestune B70 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo Standard ']
Car name = ['Bestune B70 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo Comfort ']
Car name = ['Bestune B70 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo Deluxe ']
Car name = ['Bestune T33 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.6 A/T Luxury ']
Car name = ['Bestune T33 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.6 A/T Premium ']
Car name = ['Bestune T55 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo Deluxe ']
Car name = ['Bestune T55 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo Premium ']
Car name = ['Bestune T55 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo Premium Plus ']
Car name = ['Bestune T77 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo Deluxe ']
Car name = ['Bestune T77 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo Premium ']
Car name = ['Bestune T77 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Turbo Premium Plus ']
Car name = ['Brilliance V6 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Deluxe ']
Car name = ['Brilliance V6 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Grand Deluxe ']
Car name = ['Brilliance V6 '] Model = ['2021'] Engine = ['1.5 A/T Flagship ']
Car name = ['Changan Alsvin '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['1.4 M/T L1 ']
Car name = ['Changan Alsvin '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['A/T L1 1.5 ']
Car name = ['Changan Alsvin '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['A/T L2 1.5 ']
Car name = ['Changan CS15 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['A/T L1 1.5 ']
Car name = ['Changan CS15 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['A/T L2 1.5 ']
Car name = ['Changan CS55 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['A/T Turbo L1 1.5 ']
Car name = ['Changan CS55 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['A/T Turbo L2 1.5 ']
Car name = ['Changan CS55 '] Model = ['2022'] Engine = ['A/T Turbo L3 1.5 ']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know where I can read about useful JavaScript code for web scraping?.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with javascript. in my experience, understanding web environments like HTML, client-server is more helpful to make a web scrapping bot.